# I want to remove redundant code and move in to a separate Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code I am trying to remove the redundant code and move the code to separate function.

```
        //Adding Infotypes to filter and checks whether any infotype option is selected
        if(this.$infoOptions.val() != null){
          var infotypelength = this.$infoOptions.val().length;
          var l=0,j;
          //Condition to check empty input type
          if( infotypelength > 0){
              var infotypeList = this.$infoOptions.val();
              for(j = 0; j < infotypelength; j++) {
                //It checks whether already option is selected and prevents adding to filter if its duplicate.
                if(($.inArray( $('#infoOptions').select2('data')[j].text, filterList)) == -1 ){
                  this.filter.push($('#infoOptions').select2('data')[j].text);
                  if(infotypeList[j].contains('_subgroup')){
                     var res = infotypeList[j].split("_");
                     this.aSubinfotype[l]=res[0];
                     l=l+1;
                  }
                  else
                   this.aInfotypes.push(infotypeList[j]);
                }
              }
           }
        }

        //Adding Countries to filter
        if(this.$countryOptions.val() != null){
          var geoLength = this.$countryOptions.val().length;
          //Condition to check empty input type
          if( geoLength > 0){
              var geoList = this.$countryOptions.val();
              var l=0;
              for(var j = 0; j < geoLength; j++) {
                if(($.inArray( $('#countryOptions').select2('data')[j].text, filterList)) == -1 ){
                    this.filter.push($('#countryOptions').select2('data')[j].text);
                    if(geoList[j].contains('_subgroup')){
                       var res = geoList[j].split("_");
                       this.aSubgeotype[l]=res[0];
                       l=l+1;
                    }
                    else
                     this.aGeography.push(geoList[j]);
                }
              }
           }
        }
```

But I am facing problem in passing the variable and cached selectors in to other function. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You don't need hour help to do that... Extract your differents data between the both block, make a function with these data in parameter...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am stuck withe below part,   1. how can I pass the cached selector( I mean $('#infoOptions').select2('data')) to the function() as an argument so as to use it dynamically...2. I want to push the value to my global variable and not in the local scoped array..  please help me with some example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how is done your implementation but I really think that you can improve it, by the way, you can reduce your code in two way bit different :

```
var myFunction = function(option, filter, array, selector, subType) {
    if(option && option.val()){
        var optList = option.val();
        var optLength = optList.length;
        //Condition to check empty input type
        if( optLength > 0) {
            var l = 0;
            for(var j = 0; j < optLength; j++) {
                if( ($.inArray( selector.select2('data')[j].text, filterList)) == -1 ){
                    filter.push(selector.select2('data')[j].text);
                    if(optList[j].contains('_subgroup')){
                        var res = optList[j].split("_");
                        subType[l]=res[0];
                        l=l+1;
                    } else {
                        array.push(optList[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call : `myFunction(this.$countryOptions, this.filter, this.aGeography, $('#countryOptions'), this.aSubgeotype)`

```
// data = {option, filter, array, selector, subType}
var myFunction = function(data) {
    if(data.option && data.option.val()){
        var optList = data.option.val();
        var optLength = optList.length;
        //Condition to check empty input type
        if( optLength > 0) {
            var l = 0;
            for(var j = 0; j < optLength; j++) {
                if( ($.inArray( data.selector.select2('data')[j].text, filterList)) == -1 ){
                    data.filter.push(data.selector.select2('data')[j].text);
                    if(optList[j].contains('_subgroup')){
                        var res = optList[j].split("_");
                        data.subType[l]=res[0];
                        l=l+1;
                    } else {
                        data.array.push(optList[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call :

```
myFunction({
    option: this.$countryOptions,
    filter: this.filter,
    array: this.aGeography,
    selector: $('#countryOptions'),
    subType: this.aSubgeotype
});
```

or

```
var data = {
    option: this.$countryOptions,
    filter: this.filter,
    array: this.aGeography,
    selector: $('#countryOptions'),
    subType: this.aSubgeotype
}
myFunction(data);
```

The first way is to pass your data one by one, the second you pass your data into an json object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This certainly helps me to proceed further.. Thanks again!